# Pandas 'dupout' how to view removed duplicate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

In `pandas` I am using `drop_duplicates(subset='Full Name', inplace=True)` to remove duplicate records, however I would like to view the removed duplicate records for manual inspection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and parameter `keep=False` for return all dupes with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Full Name':list('abcdac'),
                   'Some val':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})

print (df)
  Full Name  Some val
0         a         4
1         b         5
2         c         4
3         d         5
4         a         5
5         c         4

df = df[df.duplicated(subset='Full Name', keep=False)]
print (df)
  Full Name  Some val
0         a         4
2         c         4
4         a         5
5         c         4
```